# How do I convert delegate R Function<T,R>(T t) to Func<T,R>?

Tags: c#, delegates, func

I've got legacy code that defined the following helper

```
public delegate R Function<T, R>(T t);
```

But I want to supply a `Func<T,TResult>`

casting attempts fail to compile

> Cannot convert type '`System.Func<T,TResult>`' to '`Rhino.Mocks.Function<T,TResult>`'

Is there a way that not only compiles, but functions at runtime?

Answer (score 9):

The problem is you are trying to combine two different delegate types: `Func<T, TResult>` and `Function<T, TResult>`.  Even though they have the same signature they are different, and hence incompatible, types.

Use a lambda to create a conversion layer between the two.

```
Func<T, TResult> func = ...;
TheMethod(x => func(x));
```

Comment: ah, right. writing things out is too often my last resort. Will accept once SO allows.

Answer (score 9):

Jared and phoog are both correct. A third way to do the same thing, just to round it out, is:

```
Func<int, string> func = i => i.ToString();
Function<int, string> function = func.Invoke;
```

That is, the new delegate is a delegate to *the invoke method of the first delegate*, which has the correct signature.

That one has to do this is vexing in the extreme.  Were we designing the runtime from scratch today, knowing what we now known about how people use delegate types, I think it likely that there would either be *one* built in delegate type for each signature (much as there is *one* "single dimensional array of integers" type), or that there would be "structural identity" amongst delegate types. Next time you design the type system for a virtual machine, keep that in mind.

Comment: I'm not sure if the runtime is the right level to attack this issue. In particular I'm not sure how well those changes would interact with parameter names.

Comment: If implementing this feature was free (i.e., would not require testing, take developer time away from other features, started at 0 points rather than -100 points, etc.), would there be any major downsides to implementing it?

Comment: If I understand correctly, since it doesn't compile, it wouldn't help for the runtime to be ok with it.

Comment: @Brian: There are definitely benefits to non-structural typing of delegates; they are just benefits that in practice people have not taken advantage of. For example, you could have a delegate "delegate int Pure(int x);" and the convention that *only pure methods may be referred to by a Pure delegate.*

Answer (score 8):

You can create a lambda as JaredPar suggests, or pass one to the constructor of the other:

```
Func<int, string> f1 = i => i.ToString();
Function<int, string> f2 = new Function<int, string>(f1);
```

Comment: Thanks to @EricLippert for fixing the lambda expression; I had spent some of the afternoon working in F#, which uses `->` instead of `=>`.